# C# sending multiple emails asynchronously with cancellation token

Tags: c#, async-await, smtpclient

I am trying to send multiple messages using SendMailAsync and I am trying to pass a cancellation token to interrupt the sending process when the cancellation has been requested.

```
static void Send(SmtpClientFactory factory, IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages)
{
    Task.WaitAll(SendAsync(factory, messages, CancellationToken.None));
}

static async Task SendAsync(SmtpClientFactory factory, IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = factory())
        {
            foreach (MailMessage message in messages)
            {
                await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
    }, token);
}
```

When I use the non-async Send, it gets into a deadlock. How can I send my message synchrnously and use a cancellation token to cancel when the time is up?

Comment: You shouldn't need to run the method into a Task.Run as SmtpClient is async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `CancellationToken.Register` and `SmtpClient.SendAsyncCancel` to do what you need:

```
static async Task SendAsync(SmtpClientFactory factory, IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages, CancellationToken token)
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        using (SmtpClient smtpClient = factory())
        {
            foreach (MailMessage message in messages)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                using (token.Register(() => smtpClient.SendAsyncCancel()))
                {
                    await smtpClient.SendMailAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            }
        }
    }, token);
}
```

Keep in mind that `SmtpClient` is [officially deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient):

> SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead

Not only is MailKit threadsafe, but it's far more flexible in terms of message construction, and it supports `CancellationToken` to boot!

Comment: This still causes a deadlock in an ASP.NET web application (when using `Task.WaitAll` with the Send method in my question).

Comment: Does your WaitAll result in the same instance of SmtpClient being used in parallel? That's not supported

Comment: @RichardSzalay - you could move the token operations outside the `for`; no need to do them for each iteration?

Comment: @RichardSzalay no, different instances.